# How can I add features (points) to my byte (eight bit unsigned integer) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, features, geospatial-pdf

I have a series of data (in Byte - eight bit format) with PDF as GDAL (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library) Driver. My goal is to add point features to it using QGIS, however so far I haven't been able to. I assumed this can be done using "toggle editing" feature but it seems that I can't. How can I add point features using QGIS?

Below is a screenshot of my data:

[image: Byte data opened in QGIS]

Comment: What do you mean by "point feature"?

Comment: @Stu Smith, by point feature I mean point symbology. Hope this makes sense. Here is a link to an example: https://geomanila.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/a.jpg